# Unique Equipped - Two Differently Named Rings

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering in Diablo 3 if I got two different rings, a Manald Heal and Puzzle Ring for example, would I be able to wear both or would it still stop me from wearing one of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Unique equipped" only refers to one specific named item at a time, so yes, you can wear both for maximum bling bling.